# Google PlacePicker API - geo coordinate precision after the decimal (Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3, google-places-api

I'm using Google PlacePicker API in my iOS application using Swift 3.0.
I need 13 digits of precision after the decimal. But Google PlacePicker is returning latitude and longitude with 7 digits after the decimal.

Below is my function:

```
func pickPlace(sender: UIButton) {
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
    let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude + 0.001, longitude: center.longitude + 0.001)
    let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude - 0.001, longitude: center.longitude - 0.001)
    let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)
    let placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)
    placePicker.pickPlace(callback: {(place, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        if let place = place { 
            let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude)
            let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinates)
            marker.title = place.name
            marker.map = self.googleMapView
            self.googleMapView.animate(toLocation: coordinates)
            let geoCode = "\(place.coordinate.latitude),\(place.coordinate.longitude)"
            self.showGeoSelector(title: "Selected Coordinates", message: "Latitude: " + String(place.coordinate.latitude) + " Longitude: " + String(place.coordinate.longitude), geoCode: geoCode, geoLat: String(place.coordinate.latitude), geoLong: String(place.coordinate.longitude))
        }  
    }) 
}
```

Comment: 7 decimal places gives nearly centimeter precision. Why do you want more than that?

Comment: Why then the same place coordinates lat long value returned by Google Map is in 13 decimal place and that by Google Place Picker is in 7 decimal places ? Thanks Andrew for your reply

Comment: When you say "returned by Google Map" do you mean the Maps iOS API, the maps.google.com website, something else?

Comment: Google Maps API

Comment: I still don't understand exactly what your problem is. You're getting a lat,lng from a GMSPlace, adding a marker on the map at that location and then....?? Is it possible that you're just running into normal floating point precision issues?

Comment: 7 decimal places in Google Places and 13 decimal places in Google Maps for the same place. Is that fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
let geoCode = "\(String(format: "%.18f", place.coordinate.latitude)),\(String(format: "%.18f", place.coordinate.longitude))"
```

Hope its helps :)

Comment: Thanks @userar for your quick response.. I tried your code.. It seems to be working. But a lot of zeroes repeating after the 7th decimal place.. Tried for different locations from the map.. It looks like 25.34390480000000077, 55.396507300000003227. Thinking about the accuracy of these values..